# Chrome-based lags on JavaScript performance

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

I have a problem with JavaScript performance only on Google Chrome browser. The problem is that for some time website is running smoothly, but after several seconds browsing the page just freezes for 2 or 3 seconds. I think an issue could be with synchronaus ar cyclic method calls. But then the question is why, i.e., Mozilla Firefox or Microsoft Intenet Explorer do not freeze?

Actually, I don't even know what exactly to ask, but I think I will be able to know the answer if someone of you could show me possible ways to solve the problem. To make matters more clear, I will show you Google Chrome Timeline I got:
[Google Chrome Timeline http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/5998/timelinen.png](http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/5998/timelinen.png)
As you can see, it shows that for some time processor parses JavaScript smoothly, but after several seconds JavaScript parsing just freezes.

So, do you have any ideas what could cause such type of problem? Any help would be appreciated. If you need more info, do not hesitate to ask. I will try to tell everything you need if I will know myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something like that when I used very big sprite. I think google chrome has a performance problem with image processing. Mozila firefox and opera works smoother.

If you have big sprite (bigger than 2000x2000) try to split to smaller pieces.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer was useful. I splitted my sprite whose width and height ratio was 6000px on 1500px into four images. And that worked. :)

Comment: @VaidotasStrazdas: I think you use sprites too big. I splited to 1000x1000 and all perfoemance issues goes off.